# Magento2: custom template for custom product type

Tags: magento2, product, layout-update

I'm having different type of products on my website with different layouts. So I've created a custom product type but don't know how to set a custom template for my custom product type. So when someone browse the product they will see different product layout and not the default one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to customize the whole page or some specific part , like media section , products info section or something else ?

Answer (score 3):

If you've created a custom product type called "test" you should create a new layout file at 
`<vendor>/<module>/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_test.xml` and adjust your layout from there.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can I copy/paste the content from catalog_category_view_type_default.xml file?

Comment: No, `catalog_category_view_type_default.xml` is for the category view.

And I think your custom file `catalog_product_view_type_test.xml` should inherit it's layout from the default `catalog_product_view.xml`, so you only need to add your desired changes.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry that was by mistake. Yes, I've created a file catalog_product_view_type_rooms.xml and its working properly. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Accept the answer, if you don't mind, so others can easily find the solution.